# get user id from petition and inserted in other table

Tags: mysql, database

help me how to get user id from this table,with example petition_id = 52 then if get all user_id  i want inserted to second table (auto_increment) in SYSTEMID

this my command :

```
$result = $db->Execute("SELECT petition_id,MT4ACCOUNTID, phpfox_petition_text.petition_goal,user_id  " . "from phpfox_petition_text,phpfox_tradeusers " . "where  phpfox_petition_text.petition_goal = $mt4acctid and user_id=$systemid ");
        $symbol1 = $result->fields[0];
        $symbol14 = $result->fields[3];

$result212 = $db->Execute("SELECT petition_id, user_id " . "from phpfox_petition_sign " . "where  petition_id=".$symbol1." and MT4ACCOUNTID=$mt4acctid ORDER BY time_stamp DESC");
  $symbol122 = $result212->fields[1];

  $result111 = $db->Execute("SELECT full_name  " . "from phpfox_user " . "where  user_id=$systemid ");
        $symbol1user = $result111->fields[0];


        $record = array();
        $record["SYMBOL"] = $symbol;
        $record["CMD"] = $cmd;
        $record["VOLUME"] = $volume;
        $record["PRICE"] = $price;
        $record["SLIPPAGE"] = $slippage;
        $record["STOPLOSS"] = $stoploss;
        $record["TAKEPROFIT"] = $takeprofit;
        $record["COMMENT"] = 'MyfaceFx>Copied from ::'.$symbol1user;
        $record["MAGIC"] = $magic;
        $record["EXPIRATION"] = $expiration;
        $record["MT4SIGNALID"] = $signalid;
        $record["BROKERNAME"] = $brokername;
        $record["MT4ACCTID"] = $mt4acctid;
        $record["TIMESTAMP"] = time();
        $record["SYSTEMID"] =$symbol122;
        $record["ORDERUNITS"] = $basecurrencyunits;
        $record["ACCTBALANCE"] = $acctbalance;
        $record["ACCTCURRENCY"] = $acctcurrency;

    $insertSQL = $db->AutoExecute('phpfox_tradesignals', $record, 'INSERT');
    $insertsignalid = $db->Insert_ID();
```

its working but only get 1 result like this :

```
   expiration : systemid       
    ...............................................................

              : 27
```

but i want get result like this :

```
   expiration : systemid       
    ...............................................................

              : 27 

              : 29 

              : 26

              : 34
 etc....
```

Table PETITION

```
   petition_id : user_id        
    ...............................................................
    50       : 35   
    52       : 27 
    40       : 23  
    52       : 29 
    50       : 35   
    52       : 26
    40       : 23  
    52       : 34
   etc....
```

Table SYSTEMID

```
   expiration : systemid       
    ...............................................................
```

Comment: Your Code is too messed up!!

Comment: The state of this question makes me queezy

Comment: Can you please arrange the code? Add 2 spaces at the end of each line and press enter to show 2 separated lines. Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to insert a value from one table into another:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (systemid)
SELECT user_id
FROM   table1
WHERE  petition_id = 52
```